# Header overlap with description in invoice from second page

Tags: report, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

While printing an invoice, If the first order is pretty big, then the second page is overlaped by both heading and description

[image: report]

Comment: What version of wkhtmltopdf are you using? You should activate Windows haha

Comment: Version used is 0.12.2.4. I dont think version is an issue. I also tried the updated version of mine

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a version issue.

The version must be "qt patched". Check if one of [these versions](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.1.3/) (0.12.1.3 qt patched) solve the problem